# Capture real time movement or sound directly from my machine

Tags: python

I have coded a similar version of the dinosaur game from chrome. I'm trying to generate a screen recording of bot playing the game. Whenever it breaks I have a set of actions I now trigger manually but I'd like to have 24/7 catching and restarting.

It is playing when my computer still has music or movement. STUCK status of the game would be no music or frozen screen, and then trigger some action with [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The idea is to do it externally from the source code of the game.

Can't find any poolling of the sound real time (all are hearing to files) or screen movement to trigger.